# Grep file, if pattern 1 then do continue, if pattern 2 exit 100

Tags: bash, shell

Just need some help with a shell script in which i need to grep a log file for either of 2 strings and do either of 2 actions depending on which one is found.

I was using "until" to grep for the successful message before continuing but i do not want this program executing continuously if it never arrives.

Grep file1

IF "BUILD FAILED" found then exit 100
IF "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" found then continue with my script.

I couldn't find this specific answer in any other thread and although probably trivial, its causing me some pain.

Appreciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to check if a string exists in a file. `-c` flag of grep can be used for this.

But you cannot handle a case where both the Strings are not present in the file? If either one will surely be present, you can use this code to check only for "BUILD FAILED".

```
if grep -q "BUILD FAILED" file.txt; then
    exit 100
fi
```

Comment: thats perfect. one will always be present yes